# TikZ: configuring arrow tip appearance not working according to documentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I'm trying to follow the details outlined in the manual for configuring the appearance of arrow tips.  But, I get nothing but errors.

I'm trying to get the examples from section 16.3 on *Arrow keys* to work.  Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\listfiles
\begin{document}

  \tikz{\draw[-{Stealth[length=5mm]}] (0,0) -- (2,0);}

\end{document}
```

which generates the following error:

```
! Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip kind 'Stealth'.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9       \tikz{\draw[-{Stealth[length=5mm]}]
                                              (0,0) -- (2,0);}
?
```

If I'm not loading the correct libraries, I'm not sure what they should be.

If I try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\listfiles
\begin{document}

  \tikz{\draw[-{stealth[length=5mm]}] (0,0) -- (2,0);}

\end{document}
```

*Note* `stealth` this time (as opposed to `Stealth`).  I get the error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key 'length', to which you passed '5
mm', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9       \tikz{\draw[-{stealth[length=5mm]}]
                                              (0,0) -- (2,0);}
?
```

What am I not doing correctly?

### *PS:* I'm using a CVS version of TikZ dated September 30, 2013:

From `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
     pgf.sty    2013/08/23 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.13)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/11/07 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.25)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/08/23 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.46)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.1)
    tikz.sty    2013/09/30 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.138)
  pgffor.sty    2013/07/18 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.24)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `arrows` library is depreciated.  Use `arrows.meta` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136190/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\listfiles
\begin{document}

  \tikz{\draw[-{Stealth[length=5mm]}] (0,0) -- (2,0);}

\end{document}
```

[image: arrow with length option]

Comment: So I have a couple of questions: (1) There's no place at the beginning of chapter 16 that informs the user that they need a special library for this feature--though now I see `arrows.meta` is buried in the introductory material--how do I make recommendations that this be displayed more prominently?  (2) Where do I read or how do I learn about which libraries are deprecated and which aren't?

Comment: I found it by looking in the documentation for the "arrows" library under "Libraries".  (I only found out about this new feature because I looked for Section 16.3 in my PGF manual, found it was about nodes, and wondered what was going on.  So I updated PGF and it all appeared.)  Yes, it could probably be made more explicit in the new documentation on arrows.  This can be reported on the PGF bug tracker on sourceforge.

Comment: But remember that this is the *CVS* version so one should expect that there will be gaps in the documentation.  On the other hand, the only way that they will fill in the gaps is if people report them so definitely go ahead and report it.

Comment: I am aware of the risks with the CVS versions. :)  I've been eagerly awaiting this new feature.  So, I'm glad you could help me out on this.  I'll report this matter of documentation to the PGF bug tracker later today.  Thanks again.