# arrows.meta in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex, tikz-arrows

I have an up-to-date MikTeX 2.9 installation with tikz/pgf 3.0, but trying to compile

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=4pt]
\draw [red!50!black, -Stealth] (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [green!50!black, -{Stealth[slant=-0.5]}] (0,1) -- (3,1);
\draw [blue!50!black, {Square[slant=-0.5,length=\the\pgflinewidth]}-{Stealth[slant=-0.5]}] (0,2) -- (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(taken from [TikZ: configuring arrow tip appearance not working according to documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136190/tikz-configuring-arrow-tip-appearance-not-working-according-to-documentation)) gives 906 errors beginning with

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.28 \pgfarrowsaddtolengthscalelist
                                   \pgfarrowlength
```

The arrows.meta library has

```
\ProvidesFileRCS[v\pgfversion] $Header: /cvsroot/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex,v 1.12 2013/12/13 15:11:58 tantau Exp $
```

in its header.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
In the end it says

```
! I can't find file `tikzlibrary.code.tex'.
```

Where do I get this file from and where shall I put it? I don't find it in the zip file from sourceforge.

Comment: Works fine here, with TeX Live 2013.

Comment: Works fine here on MikTeX 2.9. Please add `\listfiles` to your preamble, recompile, and take a look at the `.log` file. You can add the bits from `*File List*` to `***********` (near the end of the file) to your question for us to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found it. MiKTeX didn't update the files in

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\tex\generic\pgf
```

Updating them to the current versions via sourceforge results in the above example working. Don't know why they didn't got updated, though.
Thanks a lot to the commentors!

Comment: You'll be back soon if you did it manually.

Comment: Well, do you have an idea why MiKTeX didn't update them?

Comment: Did you run the `Update (Admin)` or `Update [plain]` (from your Start Menu)? You need to run both to get all updates. Depending on how packages were initially installed (on-the-fly, explicitly, or explicitly as admin); you need to run Update under the same privileges as the original package install.

Comment: All packages are installed as admin, since I had the problems you described before, thus I used Update (Admin). It's an idea to check next time nevertheless, thanks.

Comment: @John: But see also [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67712).

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone has the same problem I did -- the file wasn't found on ArXiv, which is using texlive from 2011 -- it seems the quickest "work around" is just to use `arrows` instead of `arrows.meta` and adapt files accordingly.