# Does pgf 3.0.0 on ctan not have the arrows.meta tikz library?

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex, tikz-cd

Ever since upgrading to `pgf 3.0.0` and `tikz-cd 0.9b`, I cannot load the tikz-cd package. The issue seems to be with the `arrows.meta` tikz library. The following MWE throws up 3 errors and a warning, also listed below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

The errors from the `.log` file are as follows:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 17, version
               `2013/12/13' of package tikz,
               but only version
               `2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)'
               is available.
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/handlers/first char syntax' an
d I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.38 \pgfkeys{/handlers/first char syntax=true}

! I can't find file `tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex'.
<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex 
                                                  \catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...
l.18 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,quotes,arrows.meta}

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex 
                                                  \catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...
l.18 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,quotes,arrows.meta}
```

From the version mismatch warning, I'm thinking MiKTeX acquired some not-updated version of pgf. How do I confirm and work around this, if that is the issue?

Comment: Your MWE works nicely with TexLive 2013, so I do not think this is an issue with the package on CTAN. The `arrows.meta` package is included in pgf 3.0, to quote the manual: "The only reason this library is not loaded by default is for compatibility with older versions of TikZ. You
can, however, safely load and use this library alongside the older libraries arrows and arrows.spaced." Are you sure that pgf 3.0 is actually installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems MiKTeX installed two different versions of pgf, one through Package Manager, and one through Package Manager (Admin). Running the non-admin Update removed one copy (this idea was from [arrows.meta in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165585/arrows-meta-in-tikz)), and then the compilation was successful. If anyone has more details on why this happened, you're welcome to add another answer.

Comment: This is only be plausible, when you have on every update a different mirror assigned, and got an outdated mirror, but then you would very, very probably not have got updates for other packages, too. I suspect the real reason is what is described in [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67712) An update as admin is not seen, when you have as user an older version installed.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but I'm not using MiKTeX. Does anyone know how to fix this for MacTeX?