# Simple Block Diagram (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, block, flow-charts

It's the first time for me using the TikZ package. I wanted to build such a block diagram but it is becoming really hard. The diagram below was made with Word and it looks pretty inaccurate. Could anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Have you ever used TikZ before? See for example [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237765/block-diagram-using-tikz?rq=1) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209355/drawing-a-block-diagram-using-tikz?rq=1).

Comment: Also. could you elaborate on what you want to change about this? Accuracy in terms of what?

Comment: welcome! start small, and build up :) start by creating one node with some text, then another, then connect them, then build from there. lots of people could answer this, but it will be more valuable for you if you try something yourself and then let us know which bit is giving you trouble

Answer (score 4):

Just start at one end and work your way through

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % I tend to like placing nodes manually
  \begin{scope}[minimum width=15mm,minimum height=10mm]
    \node[draw] (v1) at (0,0) {$v_1$};
    \node[draw] (v2) at ($(v1)+(6,0)$) {$v_2$};
    \node[draw] (v3) at ($(v1)!0.5!(v2)+(0,-2)$) {$v_3$};
    \node[draw] (v32) at ($(v1)+(0,-4)$) {$v_3$};
    \node[draw] (v33) at ($(v32)+(0,-12mm)$) {$v_3$};
    \node[draw] (v34) at ($(v33)+(0,-12mm)$) {$v_3$};
    \node[draw] (v35) at ($(v34)+(0,-12mm)$) {$v_3$};
    \node[draw] (v36) at ($(v35)+(0,-12mm)$) {$v_3$};
    %
    \node[draw] (v37) at ($(v36)+(-4,2)$) {$v_3$};
    \node[draw] (v38) at ($(v37)+(0,-12mm)$) {$v_3$};
    \node[draw] (v39) at ($(v38)+(0,-12mm)$) {$v_3$};
    \node[draw] (v40) at ($(v39)+(0,-12mm)$) {$v_3$};
  \end{scope}
  % arrows
  \draw[->] (v1) -- (v2);
  \draw[->] (v3) -- (v3 |- v2);
  \foreach \n in {32,33,34,35} {
    \draw (v\n) -| (v2);
  }
  \draw[->] (v36) -| (v2);
  % 
  \foreach \n in {37,38,39,40} {
    \draw (v36.west) -- (v\n.east);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Zarko it's my default class in Emacs so shows up automatically ;-)

Comment: memoir It is my favorite document class, but images (alone)  I usually draw in standalone :-)

Comment: @Zarko I've started using standalone, but often it is just as fast to do what I normally do: screen grab + cut in gimp

Answer (score 3):

And one more with TikZ ... style inspired by Bernard answer, node positions are determined relatively by power of tikz library `chains`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,shadows}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 3mm and 21 mm,
      start chain = A going below,
every node/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=white,
                     minimum width=12mm, minimum height=6mm,
                     drop shadow,
                     on chain=A}
                        ]   
% main column
\node                       {$v_1$};            % A-1
\node[below=12mm of A-1]    {$v_2$};            % A-2
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,4}% since all have the same content
\node                       {$v_3$};            % A-3 ... A-6
% left subcolumn
\node[left=of $(A-4)!0.5!(A-5)$]    {$v_3$};    % A-7
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3}% since all have the same content
\node                       {$v_3$};            % A-8                   
% right node
\node[right=of A-1]         {$v_2$};            % A-11
% arrows top
    \draw[->] (A-1) -- node[below=6mm] {$v_3$} (A-11);
    \draw[->] (A-12) -- (A-1 -| A-12);
% arrows right
\foreach \i in {2,3,...,5}
    \draw (A-\i) -- (A-\i -| A-11);
% last arrow right 
\draw[->] (A-6) -| (A-11);
% last arrow left
\foreach \i in {7,8,...,10}
    \draw (A-\i.east) -- (A-6.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

The comments in code is intended to easy find what parts of code doing. For better understanding it is recommendable to read TikZ manual, part 3 (TikZ ist kein Zaichenprogram).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One can do  something nicer than Word with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, x11names]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %

\usepackage{pstricks-add, pst-blur, auto-pst-pdf}

\newcommand\myframe[2]{\psDefBoxNodes{#1}{\psframebox[framesep=8pt, shadow,  blur]{\quad#2\quad}}}
\newcommand\Vframe[1]{\myframe{#1}{$ V_3 $}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
    \psset{linearc=0.05, framearc=0.25, framesep=0.3, shadowcolor=SteelBlue4!60, shadowangle=-90, arrowinset=0.15, emnode=p}%
    %%% nodes
    \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.25, colsep=1.6,mnode = r]%
        & \myframe{V1}{$V_1$} & \pnode{J} & \myframe{V2}{$V_2$} \\[3ex]
        & &  \Vframe{V3} \\[3ex]
         & \Vframe{V32} \\
         & \Vframe{V42} \\
      \Vframe{V51}   & \Vframe{V52} \\
      \Vframe{V61}   & \Vframe{V62} \\
      \Vframe{V71}   & \Vframe{V72} \\
      \Vframe{V81}
    \end{psmatrix}
    %%% arrows
    \ncline[arrows=->]{V1:Cr}{V2:Cl}
    \ncline[arrows=->]{V3:tC}{J}
    \ncline{V51:br}{V72:Cl}
    \ncline{V61:br}{V72:Cl}
    \ncline[arrows=->]{V71:Cr}{V72:Cl}
    \ncline{V81:tr}{V72:Cl}
    \psset{angleB=-90, nodesepB=3pt, linearc=0.1}
    \ncangle{V32:Cr}{V2:bC}
    \ncangle{V42:Cr}{V2:bC}
    \ncangle{V52:Cr}{V2:bC}
    \ncangle{V62:Cr}{V2:bC}
    \ncangle[arrows=->]{V72:Cr}{V2:bC}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]